# File to import not found or unreadable when using Rails asset gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to create a rails asset gem [whose source is here](https://github.com/shekibobo/xdan-datetimepicker-rails). The problem is that when I use the gem in try to require or import the asset files in my Rails 4 project, I get the error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: jquery.xdan.datetimepicker
```

I've inspected the paths it is looking through, and it looks like it's not actually looking in the assets directory for my gem (the gem folder isn't anywhere in the list). So, it seems like the gem isn't getting required, since if it was, the `Engine` would be getting loaded, indicating to Rails that I have an assets folder somewhere. Can anyone see what I'm missing? From what I can tell, I'm doing everything that other asset gems are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at your Gem.  In order to get it working, rename **lib/xdan_datetimepicker_rails.rb** to **lib/xdan-datetimepicker-rails.rb**.

In your Rails project, uninstall your old gem and install the new one.  To make sure it's installed properly:

```
$ rails c
> pp MyRailsApp::Application.assets.paths
```

You should see an array of paths that are in the asset pipeline.  Look for:

```
/gem/path/to/xdan-datetimepicker-rails-0.0.1/app/assets/javascripts
/gem/path/to/xdan-datetimepicker-rails-0.0.1/app/assets/stylesheets
```

**NOTE:** Restart `rails c` and/or `rails s` if you're not seeing it.

Finally, in order to use the assets:

**app/assets/javascript/application.js**

```
//= require jquery.xdan.datetimepicker
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/stylesheet.css.scss**

```
 *= require jquery.xdan.datetimepicker
```

Comment: Actually, all I had to do was rename `lib/xdan_datetimepicker_rails.rb` to match the gem name, and now everything seems to work just fine. Thanks a lot!